# How to find the number of solutions to $A+2B+C=7$?

Tags: combinatorics

This is part of a bigger problem, I am just having trouble with a specific question.
To find how many solutions $A+B+C+D=7$, such that $A,B,C,D$ are non-negative integers, has all we have to do is figure out how may ways there are to give $7$ apples to $4$ people. This is just $\binom{10}{3}$.

Now I have to find how many solutions there are when $B=C$, this is $A+2B+D=7$, it should be similar to how many ways can we give $7$ apples to $3$ students if one of them has to get an even amount. I tried to use generating functions but I end up getting $a_n=\frac{3^n+1^n}{2}$, so when $n=7$ it should give me my answer but this is obviously wrong because I know the answer should be less than $36$ since the number of ways to give $7$ apples to $3$ people is $\binom{9}{2}$.

Then I also tried regular generating functions and got $F(x)=(1-x)^{-2}(1-x^2)^{-1}$ but I don't know how to solve this without expanding all of it then adding all of the terms that will give me $x^7$.

I don't think it would be easier by using the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

This should be very simple but I am missing something.

EDIT

Exponential generating functions can be represented like this:
$(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots)^2 \times (1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\dots)$

Then the first part is $e^{2x}$ the second part is $cosh(x)$ this is $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$
$e^{2x} \times \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$
$\frac{e^{3x}+e^{x}}{2}$ this is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac12 ({3^n+1^n})x^n$
Then doesn't this mean $a_n=\frac12 (3^n+1^n)$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're not looking to find solutions in full generality (i.e. $A+2B+C=n$ for general $n$) then it wouldn't be too awful to try $B=0,1,2,3$ and then add up the number of solutions for each of those. For the general solution, generating functions really are the way forward - the best technique to use there would be partial fractions.

Comment: @πr8, I know I could do it by just trying all the different combinations, I would get $20$, but I want to know how to solve it.

Comment: When you say "how to solve it", do you mean "solve the equation for general $n$"?

Comment: @πr8, yes because when solving using generating functions that is what you are doing right, then you substitute $7$ for $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x)=(1-x)^{-2}(1-x^2)^{-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+x)}$$

Expanding into partial fractions,

$$F(x)=\frac{1/8}{1+x}+\frac{1/8}{1-x}+\frac{1/4}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1/2}{(1-x)^3}$$

So, calling $f(n)$ the number of solutions, we can extract:

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{8}(1+(-1)^n)+\frac{1}{4} (n+1)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

by considering the series expansions of each of the above components.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question with how I tried to solve it using exponential generating functions, do you know what I did wrong or why it doesn't work with exponential generating functions?

Comment: The short answer is that multiplying exponential generating functions corresponds to a different combinatorial concept than multiplying ordinary generating functions - fundamentally, you're counting something different.